# aggregate the results based on score in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

If I have set of documents as a response from elastic search,

how can I aggregate the results based on the score?  the results should have two buckets , where the first bucket has documents whose score greater than 1 and the other less than 1.

I am new to elastic search, have seen that I can use script for this, but could not get that working.

Comment: did you take a look at script aggregations. i guess score will be evaluated before aggs pipeline starts execution and will be available as doc['score'] by then. i don't know may be it works.